# Python fileinput: Keep file unchanged in case of exception

Tags: python, file-io

I have a program that uses Python 3 fileinput to replace some text within files in-place. Some files causes UnicodeDecodeError as I expect since they are non-readable/binary files, but when the exception occurs these files are completely emptied out from their content.

I can see the file content is moved to a .bak file and the original file is empty but after the exception the .bak file is removed and not written back into the original file.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(currWorkingDir):
    for file in files:
        try:
            for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(subdir, file), inplace=True, encoding='utf-8'):
                line = line.replace('XXX', 'x')
                print(line, end='')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            sys.stderr.write('binary file and should not be modified {}.\n'.format(
                os.path.join(subdir, file)))
            fileinput.close()
```

I dont know all file types that would cause UnicodeDecodeError so I cant exclude these files from the loop with an if statement.
Is there a way to "do nothing" if exception occurs and keep the file as is?

Comment: The answer is not to use `fileinput`.  Conveniences are great when they work, but if they don't fit your problem, they don't help.  This is not a hard thing to do on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a context manager for the `fileinput`. If an exception occurs, rename the backup file to the original filename.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(currWorkingDir):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        try:
            with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True, encoding='utf-8', backup='.bak') as fi:
                for line in fi:
                    line = line.replace('XXX', 'x')
                    print(line, end='')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            sys.stderr.write('binary file and should not be modified {}.\n'.format(
                os.path.join(subdir, file)))
            # If an error occurs, revert to the backup file
            os.remove(filename)
            os.rename(filename + ".bak", filename)
```